# Title over Image without using "position: relative/absolute"

Tags: html, css, image, position

I have this blog where I want the title to display over the image-thumbnail. But as you can see in this link(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHnzH.png), the title stays always in the same position.

This the HTML I have:

```
<div class="side-topart">    
                <h3>Top Articles</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="side-thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/etam-cru.jpg" />
                             <!-- Fazer um title preview apenas com php -->
                            <h2><a href="#">Street Art by ETAM CRU, in Poland.</a></h2>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="side-thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/vhils.jpg" />
                             <!-- Fazer um title preview apenas com php -->
                            <h2><a href="#">Street Art by Vhils, in Portugal.</a></h2>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="side-thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/banksy.jpg" />
                             <!-- Fazer um title preview apenas com php -->
                            <h2><a href="#">Street Art by Banksy, in the UK.</a></h2>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.side-topart {
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.side-topart ul{
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.side-thumbnail{
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

.side-thumbnail img{
    width: 330px;
    height: 130px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}

.side-thumbnail h2{
   opacity: 0.7;
   position: absolute; 
   top: 50px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 275px; 
   background: #000 ;

}

.side-thumbnail a{
    display:right;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    float: left;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 150%;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I think the problem its about positioning, so what is the easiest way without using this properties?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Play around with negative `margin`?

Comment: You are absolute positioning the `.side-thumbnail h2`. Where do you wanna place the tittle? Try removing the `float: left` of the `.side-thumbnail a` and adding a `text-align: center` to `.side-thumbnail h2`. BTW `display: right` is not a valid value.

Comment: Thanks azeós. It worked right :) feel free to answer, and I will give you a star and a +1

Comment: If that's exactly what you want, I post it as an answer.

Comment: Yes. It was exactly what I want it. If you post it as an answer it will turn the solution more visible to others with the same problem. Thanks for your help again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **floating left** the `a` inside the `h2`. Just center the `a` inside the `h2`.

Add:

```
.side-thumbnail h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Remove:

```
.side-thumbnail a {
    display: right; /* That's not a valid value */
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center the element by giving it a `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right:auto`. Try to move the image up and down with the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.

Also, you can use the CSS property `position:absolute` for the link element, and `position:relative` for his parent element. Then you can move the link via `top, right, bottom, left`.

Comment: But the image is good position. As you can see in the image, only the title captions are wrong. And if I move one, the other will get to the same place.